# making a foreignkey not required

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have these 2 models:

```
# core/models.py
Class Certificate:
    user = models.Foreignkey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             related_name='certificates')
    name = models.Charfield()
    .
    .

# users/models.py
Class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    .
    .
```

and I want to send the certificates of a user along with its other pieces of information.
this is my serializer:

```
# users/serializers.py
class CertificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the certificate object"""

    class Meta:
        model = Certificate


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the user object"""
    # TODO
    # videos = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    #     many=True,
    #     queryset=Tag.objects.all()
    # )
    certificates = CertificationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        # TODO add certificates and videos
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'phone_number', 'credit', 'points', 'certificates')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True,
                                     'label': 'گذرواژه', 'min_length': 5}}
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'certificates',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user and return it"""
        return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Update a user and return it"""
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

        return user
```

now when I want to create a new user it tells me that field certificates can not be empty, how can I make the certificates field not required?

Comment: add "blank=True" as field option to the Model where you define the field `certificates`

Comment: Don't submit in html form, submit in raw(next to form), it will work

Comment: @Jonas I don't want to create a new certificate through this URL I just want to show the existing certificates belonging to the user

Comment: @minglyu I don't have any forms or HTML, the project is just an API